# Classe não encontrada em namespace

Tags: php, mvc, namespace, autoload

Estou tentando utilizar uma classe pelo use do namespace, mas sempre gera esse erro:

> `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Database\connect' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Estudando/app/Usuario/Controller/usuarioController.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Estudando/index.php(11): app\Usuario\Controller\usuarioController->nome() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Estudando/app/Usuario/Controller/usuarioController.php on line 13`

Meu composer está dessa forma:

```
{
    "autoload" : {
      "psr-4":{
        "app\\":"app",
        "Database\\":"Database"
      }
    },
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "^2.4"
    }
}
```

A classe que quero instanciar está dessa forma:

```
namespace Database;

  class connect {
     ....
  }
```

E esta é a classe em que estou chamando:

```
namespace app\Usuario\Controller;
use \app\Usuario\Views\usuarioView;
use Database\connect;

  class usuarioController {
    public function nome(){
    }
  }
```

Consigo usar os namespaces do caminho app/ tranquilo, mas agora que precisei adicionar o database/ não estou conseguindo...

[image: Estrutura do projeto]

Comment: Você executou o comando `php composer dump-autoload` para ele registrar esse código? um outra pergunta é feito em Laravel?

Comment: Já registrei o código sim, eu estou iniciando esse padrão MVC, não estou usando nenhum framework. É mais para estudo mesmo.

Comment: Entendi Lucas! o que tem /opt/lampp/htdocs/Estudando/app/Usuario/Controller/usuarioController.php on line 1 nessa linha?

Comment: Acredito que você quis dizer na linha 13, certo? Tem isso:       $connect = new connect();

Comment: Mostre na sua pergunta a estrutura de diretório

Comment: Deixa eu tentar te ajudar dentro da pasta vendor tem pasta composer dentro de um arquivo autoload_psr4.php verifique dentro dele se existe `'Database\\' => array($baseDir . '/Database'),` ou se for difernente coloque o contéudo desse arquivo.

Comment: Olá, aparentemente na primeira vez em que registrei estava como '\\Database\\' quando di o composer dump-autoload ele começou a funcionar. De qualquer forma agradeço a ajuda, apenas vendo o conteudo do autoload_psr4.php é que pude perceber que havia algo de errado.